# Value Objects holding Entities

Tags: domain-driven-design, entities, value-objects

In the book, Eric Evans shows an example where an VALUE OBJECT holds ENTITIES. VALUE OBJECTS are immutable, ENTITIES not.

The question is: If an ENTITY that
is referenced from an VALUE OBJECT change its state, was the immutability been broken?

In my opinion **it doesn't break the immutability**, because the "value" of the
object lies on the ENTITIES array, not on their states.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Well, if you want to work with immutable value objects (which is good), you can just get a new entity state object and throw away an old one.

Comment: I think it's not necessary, besides, the value object isn't aware of state changes in referenced entities, and that's right for me.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you can mutate the entities directly through the VO or not.

Imagine a VO instance that can be shared between multiple objects. If the VO contains a mutable entity and exposes it as a public member, multiple clients may update the entity concurrently. This leads to problems you would expect not to happen with actual immutability.

If the VO only holds the ID of the referenced entity on the other hand, you would have to fetch a brand new instance from a Repository before changing it, avoiding the shared mutable state issue.

Comment: In my opinion it doesn't matter if the referenced entities change their states at any time, as I said before, the value of the object lies on the array of entities. But I'm aware of concurrency issues by exposing those entities references.

Comment: That a VO is all about the value of its attributes and that it might be immutable are two complementary but different properties. You specifically asked about *"breaks the immutability"*, not *"breaks the value"* ;)